# PyDev error on Eclipse Luna preference page

Tags: java, python-3.x, eclipse, pydev, preference

I am trying to install PyDev to my Eclipse Luna but is showing me error on the prefernce page when I try to see it's installed okay.
I have installed it through the Help->Install New Software feature from eclipse and it was fine. It's only when I try to see this through preference page it's throwing an error.

I have already tried -

1. -Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU line at the end of eclipse.ini
2. Closing and reopening Eclipse
3. Running Eclipse as Administrator

I'm on Windows 10 and my java is the latest version too.

Sorry if it sounds stupid, this is my first question to the forum, would appreciate all and any help.
Thank you.

[PyDev error on eclipse Luna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNidv.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKaBL.png)

Comment: Well what does the 'Details' say, what is in the Error Log? But Eclipse Luna is now 6 years and 13 releases old so it may just be that pydev expects something newer.

Comment: Thanks for answering - it says "Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.python.pydev (435)." after clicking the Details, and I have amended my question to include the error log.

Comment: @user3776963 Yes, that looks pretty much like it is caused by your too old Eclipse. So don't waste further time with outdated software and upgrade now. When it does not work with the current Eclipse version, show the error log as text, not as screenshot (in the _Error Log_ view you can select an item and copy it via Ctrl+C).

Comment: Danke, very much appreciated and the tips too :)

Answer (score 0):

Luna (a.k.a Eclipse 4.4) is pretty old, so, you also need to use an older version of PyDev.

If you can upgrade to use a supported version of Eclipse/PyDev, that'd probably be better, but if you have some policy around or some really old dependency see: `Need to use older Eclipse/Java/Python` in https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html for the PyDev version you need to install.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful!